# Table rows not breaking when used in a component with ngFor applied to it

Tags: angular, angular2-template

With AngularJS 2.3.1, in the following html template code:-

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>col 1</th>
     <th>col 2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>sum 1</td>
     <td>sum 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tablerow *ngFor="let i of data" [item]="i"></tablerow>
</table>
```

where the `tablerow` component html template is:-

```
<tr>
  <td>{{item.col1}}</td>
  <td>{{item.col2}}</td>
</tr>
```

when this get rendered, the table rows generated by the component aren't breaking like a normal table row does.

Why does this happen and what do I need to do to fix this? And is this a bug?

Answer (score 5):

That's not supposed to work.

Instead create your `TableRow` component with an attribute selector

```
selector: '[tablerow]'
```

and a template

```
<td>{{item.col1}}</td>
<td>{{item.col2}}</td>
```

and use it like

```
<tr tablerow *ngFor="let i of data" [item]="i"></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution can be to add in your css the next:

```
tablerow {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Where `tablerow` is your component selector `selector: 'tablerow'`

I hope help you.